Joining multiple points been cut from one end of a path to another in Illustrator
I have a path of a typeface where I copied some points from one end, pasted them at the other end and I’d like to join these two ends. I have several sharp ends and a smooth end that I want to preserve its points and stitch it to those sharp ends. At this point, I might have copied too many points since the points forming straight lines could be deleted and I planned to use the Join tool to connect these two endpoints, but later I realized it was a bit tedious to manually position the points where I’ll scale them later (using the Scale Tool) and determine where to place the blue pointer so that the width of one end aligns nicely with the other.

This is the best attempt I could make so far (neglect the coincidental pink line, as I still don’t know how it should be done). Is there a better practice for achieving this?


You can actually do this easier with the scale tool. Move one point at a corner. Move the scale pivot to corner, scale from one point so its at corner.

@joojaa Thank you so much. I didn’t experiment much with moving the scale pivot to see how the scaling would work until I tried your method by dragging the entire tip from one corner to the corner of another path after selecting the tip path using Direct Selection Tool, placing the scale pivot on it and scaling the tip at the corner adjacent to the pivot. Sometimes the scaling doesn’t go the way I want but the behavior is expected so I extended the sharp end, using provided answer below, to make the tip fit the sharp end.

I agree that what you are currently doing does seem quite tedious. There are many ways to make such an edit.  Here's a totally different approach you might want to try

With the Pen Tool, draw a simple rectangular shape to extend the length of the end piece. Make sure you have snapping enabled obviously.

With the Direct Select tool, select the two corner anchors and round them using the rounded corner widgets

Select both shapes, and use the Shape Builder tool to join the two pieces


An example


My mind must have been convoluted as I didn’t expect there to be another way to seamlessly add further tip able to be adjusted to the path. In addition to what was mentioned in the comment, I found that your method is also useful for preventing the Scale Tool from working unexpectedly when fitting the tip to the path as I encountered some sharp ends with varying geometries and adding the tip makes it easier for the Scale Tool to fit the tip to the end of the path. Thank you so much for your answer.

@làntèrn - your're welcome. Glad you found it useful.
